# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted

Tags: magento2

I have the error  PHP Fatal error:

> Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted

It is when I use one filter in catalog on Magento 2.

I changed **php.ini** `memory_limit = 1G`, but it is not working.

This is phpinfo:

[image]

and this catalog:

[image]

and the error is when I click in anywhere filter.

The code is in the core of Magento, It is supposed to work if it does not change.

Only I changed the site of filters

What I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Typically, if you have out of memory  and have memory limit at lest at recommended level, (for M2 512M), increasing the limit won't help. You have a bug in the code. It is best to check php logs to understand where in the code the problem occurs and trace stack backwards to see where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2):

805306368 bytes is 768MB, so your 1G limit is not being set. Try `1024M` instead, ideally more as 1GB isn't really enough to run Magento reliably.

Comment: It is changed, but it not working

Comment: In your screenshot it's set to 768M *locally*, so check there isn't any other `memory_limit = ` in your php.ini

Comment: Only has one memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: Is this on shared hosting? Your provider might be limiting it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your memory limit by creating a `phpinfo.php` in the pub folder file.

Example:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php.

Check your current memory limit by opening [www.yoursite.com/phpinfo.php](http://#). Increase the memory limit if this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing your memory limit is a temporary solution. You probably have some code going berserk somewhere. Try to find out why this one filter is causing such heavy load. Could you share with us how you're filtering your catalog?

Comment: It is in the core in magento, It is supposed to work if it does not change

Comment: The problem could also be in external plugins. Have you tried profiling your site to determine what process is consuming so much memory? How big is the collection and how much filters are there?

Comment: Using 1G+ memory is pretty standard for Magento. Wouldn't surprise me at all if there's no plugins here whatsoever.

Comment: @EamonnHayden Nonsense. You'll see it on some imports and internal processes (like compilation), but not your average pageview. A standard frontend category request should not touch 300 MB, much less three times that.

Comment: Well all I know is from personal experience I crashed a fresh Magento install with only a couple products with nothing special done to it, just ~500mb of memory.

Comment: I don't have external plugins. Only have a custom theme with a layout that change the site of filters

Comment: I've seen custom themes with recursive collection loading into arrays in templates. So many dangers with poorly written themes. Still, there's no telling what might be causing your issue without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but.

If you're using nginx, you can also check fastcgi parameters.
There is a line from magento recommended nginx config that overrides default php.ini value:

```
  fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=18000";
```

if you use apache, I think in the .htaccess there can be something similar

Comment: this help me with issue.

Comment: @spillmusic May i know where i need to add this? either nginx PHP or in Magento. If you share the file path and some detail information will much appreciated

Comment: @senthil it's hardcoded in the default Magento config for nginx. Try find it in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory

Answer (score 1):

Are you in production mode or development Mode ? If you are in production mode, sometimes the compile errors may result into this issue , please check into log files for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the memory size in php.ini file .

Comment: Did you read the question? They already did that

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are now .user.ini files in the docroot and pub folders, which override php.ini in the same way that .htaccess can.

PHP documentation on .user.ini files
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

And Magento issue reference:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/705